# Is there a way to give NTFS file permissions to users from other Windows installations?

Tags: windows, ntfs, user-accounts, file-permissions

I am trying to set file permissions so users from two Windows installations can access certain files from a shared NTFS hard disk, withouth resorting to give "Everyone" permissions.

From within an installation I can get rights for its local user(s), but I can't give permissions to the other user by SID:

icacls * /grant *S-1-5-21-3699620855-3856482933-2467390241-1001:R /T
*S-1-5-21-3699620855-3856482933-2467390241-1001: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.

Apparently Windows has to have record of the SID somehow. Is there a way to force it to give permissions to a "foreign" SID?

Comment: Unless you have the ability to create a domain what you want isn't possible. It wouldn't be possible on Linux either. Windows respects the permissions of another Windows installation as it should. You could also simple share the drive with the other installation, once you do, you can limit the permissions of each User.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find this powershell function that purports to do exactly what you want:

```powershell
function SetNTFSPermissionsBySid([string]$directory, [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry]$objAD)
{
    # Convert byte array sid to sid string
    $sID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $objAD.objectsid[0],0

    # Inheritance This Folder, Subfolders and Files)
    $inherit = [system.security.accesscontrol.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
    $propagation = [system.security.accesscontrol.PropagationFlags]"None"

    # Retrieve the ACL
    $aCL = Get-Acl $directory

    # Create Ace
    $accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($sID, "Modify", $inherit, $propagation, "Allow")

    # Add Ace to Acl    
    $aCL.AddAccessRule($accessrule)

    # Set Acl to the directory
    Set-Acl -aclobject $aCL -path $directory
}
```

All credit goes to [Settings NTFS Permissions by SID in PowerShell](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2011/09/02/settings-ntfs-permissions-by-sid-in-powershell/) by Remko Weijnen.

This would require PowerShell 3.0+ due to its use of `Get-Acl` and `Set-Acl`.