# Can I grant permissions on files in windows 7 using a security identifier from another machine

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, ntfs, file-permissions

I have an external hard drive, and I wish to grant permissions on some files to users from 2 different computers without having to hook it up to the 2 different computers.
I know the SID of the user on the other computer, I'd like to know if and how I can grant permissions to files using the SID.

I'm running Windows 7 Professional 64 bits, and "The Other" computer Win 7 Home Premium 64 bits, they are not in a domain, but separate computers on a home network (not even same homegroup).

Note:
Duplicated question with: [Is there a way to give NTFS file permissions to users from other Windows installations?](https://superuser.com/questions/628077/is-there-a-way-to-give-ntfs-file-permissions-to-users-from-other-windows-install)

Comment: What version of W7? And are the computers in a Domain?

Comment: Thanks @JulianKnight, I'm updating the question. (I'm on W7 pro, the other is W7 starter) and no domain, home network.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is there a way to give NTFS file permissions to users from other Windows installations?](http://superuser.com/questions/628077/is-there-a-way-to-give-ntfs-file-permissions-to-users-from-other-windows-install)

Comment: Thanks @and31415, it's indeed a duplicate, I somehow didn't find that question.

Comment: @Thomas Basically there's no way to do what you want. As a workaround you could use something like this: `icacls "file or folder" /grant:r *S-1-1-0:F` The `S-1-1-0` identifier is assigned to the **Everyone** group, which "includes all users, even anonymous users and guests." [Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330/en-us) That way you wouldn't need to worry about different SIDs. I don't know if that's acceptable for you, though. By the way, Windows 7 Starter doesn't have a 64-bit version. Did you mean to say it was 32-bit?

Comment: Thanks again, good catch, it's not starter, it's home premium, feel free to put that as an answer, that's indeed one, and in my situation, I can indeed give access to everyone.

Comment: @Thomas You're welcome. In case you're interested, this is how I found the question I linked earlier: http://superuser.com/search?q=icacls+sid

Comment: awesome, I think it's a good thing to keep my question and your answer, as I didn't know icacls, and was trying to do that via the properties. Any person looking to do that via the GUI will not necessarily look for icacls in their query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14876/discussion-between-and31415-and-thomas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Workaround

There's no way to do what you want. If you were to try anyway, you would be greeted with the following error message:

> No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.

As long as granting access to everyone is acceptable, you can use the `icacls` command like this, changing the permissions as needed:

```
icacls "file or folder" /grant:r *S-1-1-0:F
```

The `S-1-1-0` identifier is assigned to the built-in **Everyone** group, which includes all user and guest accounts. This means you don't need to worry about different SIDs.

### Further reading

- [Managing Permissions from the Command Line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.geekofalltrades.aspx)
- [Well-known security identifiers in Windows operating systems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330/en-us)
- [Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)